# Invalid JSON string on some machines

Tags: .net, httprequest, arcgis, restsharp

I wrote a very basic quick-and-dirty winforms app that uses restsharp to fetch responses from an (unauthenticated) arcGIS service and display them in a tree view. Works great.

One of the parameters on the request to the arcGIS service allows me to [specify the format of the response](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/formattypes.html), with an option to get either JSON (which is what I want) or a full HTML document (this is for viewing in a browser context). I'm passing it the value to return JSON.

However, *on **some** client machines, the response comes back as HTML*, regardless, and therefore I get a deserialization error ("invalid JSON string"). I don't know why; there's no pattern I can discern as yet.

I've tried ensuring I specify the response format using the request header. I've tried flushing the browser cache on the clients, setting a no-cache header, and even passing a dummy parameter with a new guid for each request in case the problem is that the user has previously made the identical query/request on the arcGIS service via its browser GUI.

The machines are running win7, I'm using .net 4 client profile. I don't know where to start trying to diagnose why some machines work and others don't. Grateful some guidance.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the JSON? Maybe it's something like a date/time formatting issue.

Comment: @Jonskeet, the point is that when I get the JSON back as requested, there's no problem; the problem is that on some machines, when issuing an identical request with identical parameters as one run on a machine where the whole thing works, I get back the service's HTML formatted response rather than the JSON one.

Comment: Have you checked the html? It could be an error page depending on input data or similar things.

Comment: @stefanoaltieri, I'll take a close look next time I'm in front of one of these machines, but I'm pretty sure it's the HTML equivalent of the response I'm after. Thanks

Comment: @StefanoAltieri, on second look, you're onto the problem. The HTML response is actually a message from the server: `407 Proxy Authentication Required. Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied. (12209)`. I'll start looking into that.

Comment: For the record, the solution was to have the users added to a particular firewall group on the domain that allows access to the endpoints in question.